# ¿Cómo capturar el evento click de un elemento hijo sin usar ID?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero saber cual elemento "hijo" de una lista fue clickeado sin tener que recurrir a los ID, ejemplo:
Supongamos que tenemos 2 listas(padre) y cada uno de ellas tienen 3 links(hijos):

```
<ul class="padre">
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="padre">
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

La única manera de diferenciarlos sin tener que recurrir a los "ID" es con la posición de un array:

```
var padre = document.getElementsByClassName('padre');
var array2D = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < padre.length; i++) {
    var posicionPadre = padre[i];
    array2D[i] = posicionpadre;
    var hijos = posicionPadre.children;

    for (var j = 0; j < hijos.length; j++) {
        var posicionHijo = hijos[j];
        array2D[i][j] = posicionHijo;
    }
}
```

Y de esta forma capturo cuando se hizo un click en el documento:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){});
```

Sólo me faltaría saber cual hijo de su correspondiente padre hizo click.
Planteo este ejemplo sin "ID" ya que si sigo agregando links(hijos) a cada uno de los tales le debería poner un ID diferente y es un trabajo tedioso. También se podría hacer ID auto-incrementable con javascript pero no es el caso que quiero aplicar.

Comment: El tag ul tampoco puede llevar id?

Comment: No es la idea, pero podría ser permisivo.

Comment: @FabricioNahuel puedes revisar mi respuesta?

Comment: @FabricioNahuel podrías aclarar a que te estás refiriendo con "***diferenciar***"? ¿Qué dato estás buscando obtener del hijo en el que se hizo click?

Comment: @FabricioNahuel si no marcas como valido alguna respuesta, no se vale!!!

Comment: @Mariano quería diferenciarlo según la posición de un array o por su value quwson los textos que se encuentran dentro de las <a> ejemplo: Link1, Link2, etc.; ya que son las únicas diferencias entre si. Perdón si no logro expresarme bien.

Comment: @rn3w perdón pero es que no pude contestar antes. Ahora selecciono alguna respuesta. Gracias por su colaboración y su ayuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesario agregar ids para asignarle un evento a un elemento. Por ejemplo, podemos seleccionar todos los `a` con clase `hijo`, que son hijos directos de un `li`, que a su vez es un hijo directo de un `ul` de clase `padre`:

```
var hijos = document.querySelectorAll("ul.padre > li > a.hijo");
```

Y, al seleccionarlos, les podemos asignar un evento.

Código:

```js
var hijos = document.querySelectorAll("ul.padre > li > a.hijo");

for (unHijo of hijos) {
    unHijo.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
        var hijo = evt.target;
        console.log("Se hizo click en", hijo);
        console.log("Texto del enlace:", hijo.innerText);
    });
}
```

```html
<ul class="padre">
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="padre">
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hijo">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Esto es justo a lo que me refería! Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: gracias nuevamente, ahí tilde su respuesta!

Answer (score 3):

Si es que puedes, implementa jQuery. Así quedaría:

```js
$('li.hijo').click(function(){
  alert($(this).data('dato'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="padre">
  <li class="hijo" data-dato="dato 1">
    <a href="#"> Dato 1 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hijo" data-dato="dato 2">
    <a href="#"> Dato 2 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="padre">
  <li class="hijo" data-dato="dato 3">
    <a href="#"> Dato 3 </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Con esto, no es necesario crear arreglos ni tampoco id. Según su tipo y clase, puedes obtener cualquier atributo del elemento cuando se le hace `click`.

Comment: Este ejemplo también es bueno a la hora de implementar Jquery, lo tendré en cuenta! Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro que al menos te haya ayudado, exito!

Answer (score 2):

te dejo un ejemplo

debes condicionar a todos los links con el evento de click 
en tu caso son 3:

```
uno.addEventListener('click', reconocer);  
    dos.addEventListener('click', reconocer);
    tres.addEventListener('click', reconocer);
```

y con la ayuda de target puedes identificar cual de los links fue pulsado, luego con el nombre del link puedes trabajarlo para que puedas accederlo, por ejemplo se llamarian link_1, link_2, link_3 con el split puedes cortar y obtener 1, 2, 3

```
function reconocer(evt)
{
    var enlace = evt.target;
    //var arrayNombre = enlace.id.split("_");
}
```

> aca el ejemplo funcional

```js
var uno  = document.getElementById('hijo_1');
var dos  = document.getElementById('hijo_2');
var tres  = document.getElementById('hijo_3');
uno.addEventListener('click', reconocer);  
    dos.addEventListener('click', reconocer);
    tres.addEventListener('click', reconocer);

function reconocer(evt)
{
    var enlace = evt.target;
  alert(enlace.id)
    //var arrayNombre = enlace.id.split("_");
}
```

```html
<ul class="padre">
    <li><a href="#" id="hijo_1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="hijo_2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="hijo_3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

NOTA: los nombres hijo_1, hijo_2, hijo_3......... tienes que bautizarlos dinamicamente con un for

Comment: Claro con ese ejemplo funcionaría bien, pero lo que quiero en realidad es evitar los **"id"** ubicados en los tag **<a>**. @rn3w

Comment: @FabricioNahuel pero si los nombras con un for ? hijo_1, hijo_2, hijo_3...etc?

Comment: Se que funciona porque ya lo he probado, pero eh observado que algunos programadores no insertan id ni tampoco invocan funciones desde los tag desde el html, de esa manera trabajan html y javascript por separado y es mas limpio el código. Yo estaba queriendo adaptar un código viejo a esta forma de trabajo y fue la forma en la que se me ocurrió.

Comment: @FabricioNahuel es la unica forma que se me ocurre, creo que es bastante sencillo, y si hay otra solucion sera un gusto verlo.